Fetch request to back-end displaying html instead of json
server.js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../front-end/index.html'));
})

app.get('/api/users', (req, res) => { 
    const users = [{
        id: '123',
        name: 'Shaun',
    }, {
        id: '234',
        name: 'Bob',
    }, {
        id: '345',
        name: 'Sarah',
    }];

    res.json(users);
})

app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log('server is listening on port 8080');
});

main.jsx
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

fetch('/api/users')
.then(res => res.text())
.then(users => console.log(users));

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
    <div>test</div>
)

index.html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>

file structure
(https://i.sstatic.net/F0TRfNqV.png)
Expected result: console log in the browser of the user array from server.js when loading localhost:8080
Actual result: console log of index.html
Sorry if this is a noob question -- I am new to web development and have scoured google search and stackoverflow for a couple days for an explanation for why this occurs but couldn't find a definitive answer. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!
Checked the file path, file structures, package.json files, vite.config.js file, netstat on port 8080

use this :
dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html : ""
}}

as an attribute to the element that you want .
